# PHP Database Class and new() Function

Tags: php, mysql

I have, what I think/hope, is a very simple PHP question.  I have made a class to create database connections and issue common queries.  I am trying to open two different database connections by creating two objects from the same database class.  My code is as follows:

```
//connect to DB
 $dbh = new DB('localhost', 'db1', 'user', 'pass');

 //check connection
 if(!$dbh->getStatus()) {
  echo($dbh->getErrorMsg());
  die;
 }//if

 //connect to DB 2
 $dbh2 = new DB('localhost', 'db2', 'user', 'pass');

 //check connection
 if(!$dbh2->getStatus()) {
  echo($dbh2->getErrorMsg());
  die;
 }//if
```

However, when I call a method for $dbh to query the database, it attempts to query with the credentials for $dbh2.

My DB constructor is below:

```
class DB {
  function __construct($host, $db, $user, $pass) { 
   $dbh = mysql_connect($host, $user, $pass);
   mysql_select_db($db, $dbh);

   if(!$dbh) {
    $this->status = false;
    $this->error_msg = 'Error connecting to database: '.mysql_error();
    return(false);
   }//if


   $this->dbh = $dbh;
   $this->resetStatusAndErrors();
   return($dbh);
  }//_construct
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simple solution: Use [PDO](http://php.net/PDO) instead. It does exactly what you want, probably has better syntax and implementation and abstracts the interface for DB access.

Comment: Is there any way around using PDO?  The only reason I ask is because I'll have to rewrite a lot of code.  Thanks btw, will definitely use PDO in the future.

Comment: Switched everything to PDO, works like a charm!  Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

You're not showing the full class, but the most probable reason is that you are not passing the current connection to the `mysql_query()` command.

Save `$dbh` as a property of your class, and add the `connection` parameter to each `mysql_` function that accepts it:

```
mysql_query("SELECT * from.......", $this->dbh);
```

That said, if you are building this from scratch at the moment, take a look whether you don't want to use [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) instead. It is better, safer and more flexible than the old style mySQL library.

Comment: I am passing $this->dbh to every mysql_query I make

Comment: @user where are you defining `$this->dbh`?

Comment: private $dbh;  At the bottom of my class.

Comment: @user but where are you *setting* it? Edit: Ah, I overlooked that part somehow. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the `mysql` extension (using either `mysqli` or `PDO_MySQL` would give both superior performance, more features, etc., so check that for new code), you'll have to store the database handle, and use that on every `mysql_*` call:

```
class db {
....
    function query($query){
        return mysql_query($query, $this->dbh);//notice the second parameter.
    }

}
```